# R: Won't run code. Error message: cannot establish rsession

Tags: r

I am trying to run this code of 18102 rows X 7 columns of data, assigning ID by the first 
5 columns of each row. Every time I run I get the error "cannot establish connect to rsession."

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Code:

```
mydata<-read.csv("data.csv")


dd<-data.frame(mydata[,1:3], 
               X4=letters[mydata[,4]], X5=mydata[,5], 
               matrix(runif(nrow(mydata)*(18102-ncol(mydata))), nrow=nrow(mydata)))

dd$ID <- as.numeric(interaction(dd[,1:5], drop=T, lex.order=T))


write.csv(dd,file="newdata.csv")
```

Comment: I just go this to run, but the CSV file it creates is 5.5 GB large. Is there a away to compress this?

Comment: You've just created a data frame with approximately 327 million numbers in it.  Saving as `.RData` instead of `.csv` will help; a CSV file with 1 million random uniform numbers is 26 Mb, the corresponding `.RData` file is 5 Mb.  Alternatively you could use `?zip` to compress the `.csv` file after you've written it out (but not on the fly).

Comment: ben's comment is a good place to start. you can just use `save(dd,file="newdata.Rdata")` to save it as Rdata. When you want to load it again you can just use `load(file="newdata.Rdata")`. If data size becomes too much of an issue, you can look into big data packages like [data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)

Comment: perhaps I am misunderstanding exactly how this code works. My original data had 18102x7 = 126,714 entries in it. Shouldn't my new csv file have 18102x8 = 144,816 entries in it because I created a new column of ID's? why would it spit out 327 million?